# Difference between nodeJS and electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, svelte, referenceerror

I am trying to write my own home automation system in javascript. The system should have a UI so that I can access some general controls for it.

Since it requires a UI, I thought "why not make it a fat electron app".
So I am now trying out electron and svelte. But the issue I am running into is that it doesn't look like I am able to import my normal packages for controlling philips hue.

For example if I import `philips-hue` with

```
import Hue from "philips-hue";
```

it immediately throws a `ReferenceError: events is not defined` and if I try using the package `node-hue-api` it throws the same error but references `url` instead of `events`

This is quite confusing for me since I have used these packages many times before without issues when I am writing a normal node express server.

So I am wondering why it won't work on electron and svelte, and if there is any "quick fix" solutions that solves this issue?

Comment: You will need to polyfill the nodejs built-ins, eg https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/

Comment: ah, awesome! Added `rollup-plugin-node-polyfills` and moved the plugin `commonjs` up to be exectured first and then it works. So please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to polyfill the nodejs built-ins, as these do not exist in other environments such as electron.

If you are using webpack for example, you can follow the directions here: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node